# What does "Te ves como mataste un gato" mean?

Tags: expresiones

I heard this phrase from a Colombia.  What is the meaning (not literal meaning)?

Comment: There is a saying in Spanish: "Para una vez que maté a un gato, me llamaron matagatos". English: "I killed a cat once, now they call me cat killer." It is used, for instance, when someone gets a lifetime nickname for something he did just once. Maybe it has something to do with that saying.

Comment: @Charlie Qué curioso. Yo siempre lo he oído como "Mataperros. Mato a un perro y me llaman _mataperros_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This saying is about one´s facial and physical expression. "You looked like you killed a cat" tells that someone is terrified, trouble-some, perhaps. Since there´s an old believe that if you kill a cat, you'll get bad luck. I'm Colombian, and that's the use I have personally experienced for this expression.

Comment: I agree. It is basically another way of saying "you look guilty". I never heard that it brings bad luck. Maybe that they are difficult to kill (their fabled 7 or 9 lives, depending on where you live).